# Visual Studios 2008 - Multiple Projects in Solution

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I inherited an ASP.NET project, and I'm not sure what the best way to load this in Visual Studio 2008.  The client sent me the files, and this is what the file system looks like:

```
- bin (dir)
- en (dir)
- fr (dir)
- Scripts (dir)
- Web.config
```

The en directory is a duplicate of the fr directory, with the only difference between them being english text vs. french text in aspx files.   So when I tried to build a solution, Visual Studios naturally complained about functions and classes already defined in one of the folders (eg. The type "Control_topnavigtation" already contains a definition for DockXml.....because it's defined in both the en directory and the fr directory).

When I look in all the *.aspx.cs code, I can see statements like:

```
Header_global.Controls.Add(Page.LoadControl("~/en/Controls/Header_global.ascx"));
```

Notice the `~/en/` prefix....That leads me to believe the original developer did not create a unique solution for each of `en` directory and the `fr` directory.  He probably only had one solution to serve the entire project from.

I'm extremely new to .NET, so can someone tell me step by step how to configure visual studio 2008 to reproduce a development environment similar to the previous developer so I can start developing?

Comment: shouldn't you have app_data and app_code in there? If all these are both inside en and fr folders they might be just two separate projects (not sure why they are sharing one bin though).

Comment: I don't see any app_data or app_code file/directory in the files that were sent to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting all these into one project in one solution.  To avoid compilation errors, I excluded the folder i was NOT actively working on.  So if I'm working on the en site, i exclude the fr site.  if I am working on the fr site, i exclude the en site.